# Get Image File Size from UIImage Property in Swift to validate Image Size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

How can I get the File Size from UIImage Property in Swift?

My intention is to validate Images uploaded by the user. If it is above certain bytes or Size then I'll remove it otherwise allow the user to upload the file!

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I'm thinking that's a bad UX. You can either compress the image client-side (iOS) or let your backend server handle such task. Because user should not care about that at all.

Comment: Yes, You're right Brother. 

So how can I compress user Image in minimal file size?

Comment: You can get the `Data` from `UIImage` and then compare it's size.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get file size from `UIImage`, can get from the path where uploaded image stored

```
let filePath = "uploaded image url"
var fileSize : UInt64
do {

  let attr = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: (filePath?.path)!)
  fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64
  print(fileSize)

  let fileSizeWithUnit = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(fileSize), countStyle: .file)
  print("File Size: \(fileSizeWithUnit)")

} catch {
  print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as an answer, since you have a follow-up question. Since this is a bad UX, and your question is how to compress a `UIImage` in iOS, the answer is you can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. and set this param:

**compressionQuality**

> The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0
>   to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest
>   quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best
>   quality).

You could maybe have a cropping feature in your app.

Doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/1624115-uiimagejpegrepresentation